# Should a "correct" but "Inefficient* answer be down voted?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

I just got down voted because my answer was *correct* but *inefficient* (another answer showed that something could be done in *O(n)*. my answer did it in *O(n^2)*. Now, the question didn't mention - *this should be done in O(n)* . So, I gave the first(and perhaps the simplest) solution.

My question is simple (and I completely agree with the down voter that my answer is *indeed* inefficient). Is it fine to down vote a correct answer because it is inefficient?

Comment: People can vote as they want, correct answer or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People are free to downvote as they wish.

If they think that your answer is flawed, then even more so.

Comment: Sure, people can vote as they wish, but clearer guidelines would do no harm. I had an interesting discussion about this in [this now deleted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/263098/372643) with someone who downvotes answers that are "not useful" in the sense that another answer posted later is more useful. "Not useful" as a downvote tooltip can be ambiguous. (I personally only downvote answers that are incorrect, misleading, insecure or plainly a bad idea, not the ones that say something interesting, but possibly not enough.)

Comment: @Bruno - the guidelines are there, in the tooltip on the voting buttons. They are vague on purpose.

Comment: Sure, but there are so many ways to interpret "This answer is not useful". Excessive downvoting of answers that are still valid doesn't necessarily help.

Comment: @Bruno Valid doesn't mean useful.  I can write valid HTML, but only *semantic* HTML is useful.  Closer to the topic, if your solution runs in n^2 but they have 10M objects to run, then it isn't useful anymore, at least not as long as an O(n) solution exists.

Comment: @ABMagil, oh absolutely, but the example you give goes into the "bad idea" category, so would deserve a downvote. I'm just talking about answers that are correct, not bad ideas, but maybe not the best amongst the few answers provided, i.e. "not useful" in the context of a second answer that appeared later but doesn't invalidate it.

Comment: Not sure if this is adding value in this specific field of O(n) vs. O(n^2). I had a totally different topic on SuperUser, and I got the answer that downvoting for a time-intensive but working solution is not at all good practice there, see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14190/downvote-for-a-working-answer-only-because-it-means-too-much-effort-compared-to. Excerpt: "Is there a kind of rule to post only those answers which offer a solution with a needed time investment that is in good proportion with already available answers?" "What you describe absolutely is not a community rule."